# Best way to pass floating-point numbers to DDR - Zedboard

Tags: xilinx, floating-point, vivado

I have a Zedboard and I made a PL block in Vivado HLS that is going to return milions of floats to the DDR via an AXI DMA block, and those results are then going to be read by the PS from the memory.

Problem is that I can't find a way to read/write floating point numbers to the DDR since in Xilinx SDK the only functions are based or integers (i.e. Xil_Out32(..),Xil_In16(..),etc)

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't use Xil_Out32, it will kill your performances. You should use something like the AXI DMA core and connect your hardware blocks to the AXI-Stream par of the core. I don't know anything about HLS, so I'm not sure how you would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here:

http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/problem-in-passing-floating-point-values-to-custom-ip/m-p/590261#M35926

And as an answer needs to have 30 characters I'll write some blablablaa